# Listening problem : Help me identify the the exact words in this youtube video at time 1:24

Tags: listening

Help me recognize what is being said in the following video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7RVGdA9AhrY

At time 1:24 of the video, I can't quite figure out the exact words that are being said...This is roughly what I heard:

*....something...*   the work   *....something....*   created by..

Does anybody knows the correct wordings for this?

Some notes on how I tried to identify the wordings:

I downloaded the youtube video by adding cp in front of the word youtube in the URL so it becomes : https://www.cpyoutube.com/watch?v=7RVGdA9AhrY

And from the selection that appears, I chose the video quality I want to download.

To play the video at a slower pace than the default, I used vlc media player. And to slow the playback, I just pressed [ on the keyboard to have it play the video at 0.26 times slower than normal.

After I finished doing the above and played the video many times, I'm still not certain what words were being said. Perhaps because I'm having difficulty with listening British English, since English is not my native language. But I'm guessing that he could have said any of the following:

1) Whom, the work, it was created by..

2) Who, the work was created by..

3) Who, the work, it was created by..

4) other possibilities...

Which one is more grammatically correct? which one did you heard him say?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ELL is not a transcription service. For these sorts of questions, feel free to hop into [chat] and see if anyone can help.

Comment: Oh sorry, guess i'll have to close it, how do I initiate the chat to ask about this ?

Comment: Wait I think I don't have the required reputations to post there

Comment: I went ahead and gave you access to our main chat room. You can find a [list of privileges](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) in the [help]. Chat on SE sites is a blend of real-time messaging and forum posts. If no-one is around to help immediately, be patient and someone might come along later and read your message.

Comment: Slight editing of my post.. regards

Comment: I Hope this question is not off-topic anymore? If it is then please let me know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The narrator says at 1:24

> who the worksheet was created by

This has little to do with grammatical possibilities: it is what he said. My hearing and deduction was based on the narrator's introduction, which says the video is about "Excel VBA" which is programming code embedded in a spreadsheet. Each tab of an Excel spreadsheet is called a **worksheet**.